# Consolidating Dynamic Named Ranges from Separate Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, named-ranges

My initial understanding is that I may be able to use Union to solve this:

I have different dynamic named ranges for various product types on separate pages in a workbook. All carry the same start cell and column properties, but vary in length based on input data. Is there an easy way to automatically pool these entries into a consolidated list? These are not formatted tables, and I'd prefer to avoid making them into charts.

Ex: Worksheet 1 carries a list of two products (B2:B3) with associated revenue and cost figures in columns C and D. Worksheet 2 carries a list of three products (B2:B4) with... I'd like to have worksheet 3 automatically update with (B2:B6) and columns C and D with data from the original 2 worksheets. This data will grow and will be changed periodically.

Comment: Screenshots of the inputs and the expected output would help here.

Comment: Which of the columns `B:D` contain formulas and which contain values (in 1 and 2)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method to emulate UNION

```
=LET(
data1,FILTER('Worksheet 1'!B:D,'Worksheet 1'!B:B<>""),
data2,FILTER('Worksheet 2'!B:D,'Worksheet 2'!B:B<>""),
rows1,ROWS(data1),
rows2,ROWS(data2),
cols1,COLUMNS(data1),
rowindex,SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
colindex,SEQUENCE(1,cols1),
IF(
rowindex<=rows1,
INDEX(data1,rowindex,colindex),
INDEX(data2,rowindex-rows1,colindex))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know my code is probably wildly inefficient - I'm still at the beginning of my learning... Since I couldn't figure out this "union" thing, I ended up running the following code:

```
Sub dynamicRangeCons()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startCell As Range, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, ws0 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ConsItem As String
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Cons Ingredients Listing")
    ws.Activate
    Set startCell = ws.Range("B3")
    
    Set ws0 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cons Ingredients Listing")
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Spirits Ingredients Listing")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Beer Ingredients Listing")
    Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Misc Ingredients Listing")
    Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Wine Ingredients Listing")
    Set ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NA Ingredients Listing")
    
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).End(xlToRight).Column
        
    ws.Range(startCell, ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Clear
    
    ws1.Range("SpiritsItem").Copy ws0.Range("B3")
    ws1.Range("Spirits").Copy ws0.Range("C3")
    
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).Column
    
    ws2.Range("BeerItem").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol)
    ws2.Range("Beer").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol + 1)
    
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).Column
    
    ws3.Range("MiscItem").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol)
    ws3.Range("Misc").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol + 1)
    
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).Column
    
    ws4.Range("WineItem").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol)
    ws4.Range("Wine").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol + 1)
    
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).Column
    
    ws5.Range("NAItem").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol)
    ws5.Range("NA").Copy ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, lastCol + 1)

        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).Column
        
    ws.Range(startCell, ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="ConsItem", RefersTo:=Selection

        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column).End(xlToRight).Column
        
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(startCell.Row, startCell.Column + 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Cons", RefersTo:=Selection

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

### Consolidate Worksheets

- Copy the following into a standard module, e.g. `Module1`.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateProducts()
    
    Const sNamesList As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2"
    Const sFirst As String = "B2:D2"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet3"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sNames() As String: sNames = Split(sNamesList, ",")
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sNames)
    Dim nCount As Long: nCount = -1
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(0 To nUpper)
    Dim rData() As Long: ReDim rData(0 To nUpper)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim sfrrg As Range
    Dim slCell As Range
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim drCount As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To nUpper
        Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sNames(n))
        Set sfrrg = sws.Range(sFirst)
        Set slCell = Nothing
        Set slCell = sfrrg.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfrrg.Row + 1) _
                .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not slCell Is Nothing Then
            nCount = nCount + 1
            srCount = slCell.Row - sfrrg.Row + 1
            Set srg = sfrrg.Resize(srCount)
            sData(nCount) = srg.Value
            rData(nCount) = srCount
            drCount = drCount + srCount
        End If
    Next n
    
    If nCount = -1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = sfrrg.Columns.Count
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim s As Long, d As Long, c As Long
    
    For n = 0 To nCount
        For s = 1 To rData(n)
            d = d + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(d, c) = sData(n)(s, c)
            Next c
        Next s
    Next n
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim dfrrg As Range: Set dfrrg = dfCell.Resize(, cCount)
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfrrg.Resize(drCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = dfrrg _
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - dfrrg.Row - drCount - 1).Offset(drCount)
    dcrg.ClearContents

End Sub
```

- If all the data are values then to automate the previous, copy the following into each source module (not the destination (resulting) worksheet).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const sFirst As String = "B2:D2"
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With Range(sFirst)
        Set srg = .Resize(Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
    End With
    
    Dim irg As Range
    Set irg = Intersect(srg, Target)
    
    If Not srg Is Nothing Then
        ConsolidateProducts
    End If

End Sub
```