# summarising tables on separate sheets based on drop-down value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I have created different tabs/ sheets in excel each with a table. Each table has the same headers and has one column using the same drop-down list.
I want to summarise all tables into a single table in a separate sheet based on the values from the drop-down menu. In my company I cannot use VBA.
This post has answered most of my question: [Consolidating Dynamic Named Ranges from Separate Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67880473/consolidating-dynamic-named-ranges-from-separate-sheets)
The answer came from Chris Nielsen:

`=LET( data1,FILTER('Worksheet 1'!B:D,'Worksheet 1'!B:B<>""), data2,FILTER('Worksheet 2'!B:D,'Worksheet 2'!B:B<>""), rows1,ROWS(data1), rows2,ROWS(data2), cols1,COLUMNS(data1), rowindex,SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2), colindex,SEQUENCE(1,cols1), IF( rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(data1,rowindex,colindex), INDEX(data2,rowindex-rows1,colindex)) )`

I am not a coder and have tried several solutions to add more worksheets.The code works apart from displaying the results of all tables (INDEX). It does do an accurate count but shows #value as a result in all cells.

This is my start code based on the information above for only two sheets and this works:
`IF( rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(piarawaters1,rowindex,colindex), INDEX(roleystone1,rowindex-rows1,colindex)) )`

These are my tries to add another sheet:
`IF( rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(piarawaters1,rowindex,colindex), INDEX(roleystone1,rowindex-rows1,colindex) INDEX(armadalewungong1,rowindex-rows2,colindex)) )`

`IF( rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(piarawaters1,rowindex,colindex), INDEX(roleystone1,rowindex-rows1,colindex) INDEX(armadalewungong1,rowindex-(rows1+rows2),colindex)) )`

`IF( rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(piarawaters1,rowindex,colindex), INDEX(roleystone1,rowindex-rows1,colindex) INDEX(armadalewungong1,rowindex-rows1-rows2,colindex)) )`

`IF( rowindex<=rows1, INDEX(piarawaters1,rowindex,colindex), INDEX(roleystone1,rowindex-rows1,colindex) INDEX(armadalewungong1,rowindex-rows1+rows2,colindex)) )`

I hope someone can help me :)

edit to add example

[image: example link to image]

Cell C16 would be a drop-down list, the same as the status in the tables. The final table will then show only those with that status from all tables. It may not matter that the status is a drop-down.

Comment: It would be helpful to post some (dummy) data to reproduce.
Please use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to paste your sample data and paste it in your question.
With given data, explain what you expect as output.
Also I see you mention each table having a dropdown based filter. Is there a particular reason for you mentioning that?

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something like this ? **[Look_Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/xy5pqil)**

Comment: Thanks @Mayukhbhattacharya , this is what I'm trying to achieve. When using your function, excel gives the error message explaining using a comma if you don't want a function, and highlights "Date as the error for array1 in the VSTACK. Also do you mind explaining the -1 for the columns in the TAKE function?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya This is the function: `=LET(

CompleteList,VSTACK(Piara_Waters_table,Roleystone_table,Armadale_Wungong_table),

VSTACK({“Date checked”,”No”,”Street”,”Suburb”},FILTER(CompleteList,TAKE(CompleteList, ,-1)=A3)))`

Comment: replace this part: {“Date checked”,”No”,”Street”,”Suburb”} with CompleteList in your formula, that will do the job. The -1 in the TAKE function will 'take' the first column from right to left from the CompleteList, so the FILTER function will work.

Comment: =let(

piarawaters1,FILTER(Piara_Waters_table,Piara_Waters_table[Status]=$A$3,""),

roleystone1,FILTER(Roleystone_table,Roleystone_table[Status]=$A$3,""),

armadalewungong1,FILTER(Armadale_Wungong_table, Armadale_Wungong_table[Status]=$A$3,""),

rows1,ROWS(piarawaters1),

rows2,ROWS(roleystone1),

rows3,ROWS(armadalewungong1),

cols1,columns(piarawaters1),

rowindex,SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2+rows3),

colindex,SEQUENCE(1,cols1),

SummeryList,VSTACK(piarawaters1,roleystone1,armadalewungong1),

INDEX(SummeryList,rowindex,colindex)

)`

Comment: Thanks for all your help #P.b. and #MayukhBhattacharya and #TerryW!! Combining all: Success!! (It wouldn't allow me to combine my thanks and code as it was too many characters, hence two comments.)

Comment: So the formula i have suggested is working for you?